# Java2D pathfinding in 2D space shooter game

Tags: java, algorithm, awt, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I'm writing 2D space shooter game, something like space invaders, kind of. Right now I have to decide in what way
I will be moving enemy sprites and I can't move forward until I will implement some kind of solution.
Newest version of game source code on my GitHub page (link in profile).
 
 OK, so to the point. First of, I'm using only **awt**. I want to learn a lot, so I'm not using external libraries in this one. 
I want to move my aliens on a 1280x800 field with no obstacles (except other aliens and player).
First I tried to move aliens on predesigned path constructed with Bezier curves, but I was unsatisfied with the result. 
Solution lacks flexibility. So I decided to write AI for all aliens and program behavior that way. Unfortunately I didn't wrote
any pathfinding algorithm, and when I started learn about them I couldn't find anything appropriate to my situation. There is a 
pathfinding algorithm for finding way in graph, but should I treat every pixel as separate node,
or create logical nodes (couple pixels on couple pixels each), and is it a good way?
Don't take me wrong mates, I'm not looking for fast to build, easy solution. I just need some pointing in right direction, 
since my research didn't provide me with enough information. 
Should I use a Dijkstra? If yes, how to solve node problem? Or maybe there is a better way?
If you know any good web materials on pathfinding or AI, I would be thankful if you share them with me.
Thanks for getting familiar with the issue mates!

Comment: A* is commonly used, good page here: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/06/a-pathfinding-algorithm.html

Comment: So how do you want the aliens to behave? Just avoid each other? Build swarms? Move towards the player? Without a clear goal, it's hard to get to an algorithm... In other games such as Galaga, aliens just overlap and it's just fine...

Comment: Ok, let me specify.
 I'm already using standard bezier curve paths for basic drones. 
 But I also would like to add other type of aliens that are aware of players location,
and they trying to rush attack by diving close to player and bomb him. Also I need them to be able to adjust their path
 when they collide with other drones (or better, avoid collision).
And yes mate, I know that fixed paths are good enough but how I sad, I want to learn. I write this game to learn as much as I can :).